# getting direct access to data stored in vector from one class to another

Tags: c++, vector

I have a class called table, It has a vector as public member, this table class calls a method which adds data into the vector. Now i want to access these data stored in vector from table class to NextClass. I tried to use inheritance, for instance NextClass:table which works fine but in reality NextClass is not a table class it is an "has a relation to Table class",  I also tried to make class instance of the table class into NextClass, but doing so will not allow me to access data in the vector, as a resutl it returns an empty vector. Please see an abstract code of what I am trying to achieve

table class:

```
class Table
{    
    public:            
        Table();
        vector<vector<float> > vec; //innitializing vector 
        void addTableData(); //method to add data in vector
}
```

Now I have another class NextClass

```
    class NextClass
        public:
            NextClass();    
           vector<vector<float> > nextVector; //new vector to store value from above class
vector<float> innervec;
           void copyVectorToThisClass(); // method to copy vector from table class to this class
           private:
           Table table;  //also tried with making pointer Table *table but no luck
```

A method to copy vector data from table to Next class

```
void NextClass::copyVectorToThisClass(){   
 for( int i = 0; i<vec.size();i++)
        for (unsigned int ii=0; ii<table.vec.size();ii++)
            {
                innervec.assign(table.vec[i].begin()+ii,table.vec[i].end());
//also tried with vec.pushback
            }
            nextVector.push_back(innervec);
}
```

There is no error while compiling, but when I tried to check if the newVector holds any data then it returns empty that means no data transfer in the new Vector, If there is a way to manipulate pointer to point at the data inside the class table then would be great to finish this piece of code..

**Edited code**

table class:

```
class Table
{    
    public:            
        Table();
        void addTableData(); //method to add data in vector
      private:
        vector<vector<float> > vec; //innitializing vector             
}
```

Now I have another class NextClass

```
class NextClass
public:
NextClass();    
vector<vector<float> > nextVector; //new vector to store value from above class
vector<float> innervec;
           void copyVectorToThisClass(); // method to copy vector from table class to this class              
           Table table;  //also tried with making pointer Table *table but no luck    
A method to copy vector data from table to Next class   
void NextClass::copyVectorToThisClass(){   
for( int i = 0; i<vec.size();i++)
        for (unsigned int ii=0; ii<table.vec.size();ii++)
            {
                innervec.assign(table.vec[i].begin()+ii,table.vec[i].end());
//also tried with vec.pushback
            }
            nextVector.push_back(innervec);
}
```

With much appreciation.

Comment: *"I tried to use inheritance..."*  That's a bad idea.  Use inheritance when you want to model an [is a relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a).

Comment: just for the sake of information i was trying to reference that it works well with inheritance, but i donot want it be an is a relationship thats why i have problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have some conceptual errors:

- You have a table as member of nextClass, so why to copy it from table to nextVector? That seem duplicated data and it is usually very bad.
- You make the vec property in table public, which is usually a bad idea.

I suggest you a following structure:

change the copyVector to table, because as vec is part of table, it is who have the final decision about copying or not his data.

```
class table
{
....
    void getVector( const vector<float>& next ) const
}

void table::getVector( vector<float>& next ) const
{
    next = vec; //default = operator
}
```

And then, you may use it inside NextClass like that:

```
void NextClass::copyVectorToThisClass( const table& t)
{ 
    t.getVector( nextVector );
}
```

(Well, the code is made "on the fly", there is maybe a typo)

Comment: but the vector is multidimensional,

Comment: The = operator like the copy constructor make depth copy, not shadow copy, so no problem to have any levels as required.

Comment: so shall i do in this way,void getVector( const vector<vector<float>>& next ) const,   and sorry i am just learning right now

Comment: Yes, you may copy the whole vector just like that. I am not very sure of what you are doing in your double-for loop, so I cannot say if it is the same (probably not).

Comment: i tried doing this:
`void Table::getVector( const vector<vector<float>>& next ) const
{
    next = vec; 
}`

but get this error message
error: passing 'const std::vector<std::vector<float> >' as 'this' argument of 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = std::vector<float>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::vector<float> >]' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))

Comment: yes, sorry, the parameter next must not be const. Also the copyVectorToThisClass must not be const too.

Answer (score 1):

You initialize your vector at the beginning of the function, and then run the for loop to vec.size() which is 0, because there is nothing in the vector.

Comment: so, how do I accomplish this, to be honest i tried everything i can , just cant get head around ... any suggestions will be very appreciable

Comment: Run your for loop not to the size of vec, but to the size of the vector you are copying, and just push_back each value of the vector you are coping into the vector you initialize in the new class

Comment: Sorry, there was an error in the code above , i have amended it, vec is a member of class table ...

Comment: I'm still confused as to why you are running a for loop to the size of an empty vector

Comment: how do I get the size of the vector from class table

Comment: table.vec.size() since you are putting vector as a public variable, which is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an instance of class Table inside the constructor of  class NextClass
2. Using the object of class table call function addTableData() to retrieve data from file
3. Then call the function copyVectorToThisClass()

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Table {
  vector<vector<float> > vec;
  vector<vector<float> > & getDataRef() { return vec; }
};

class NextClass {
  vector<vector<float> > nextClassVec;
  public NextClass(Table t) {
    nextClassVec = t.getDataRef(); // method #1, maybe?
  }

  public readTable (const struct Table& tbl) { // method 2 ..?
    const vector<vector<float>> &tblVecRow = tbl.vec;
    for(int i = 0; i < tblVecRow.size();++i) {
      const vector<float> & tblVecData = tblVecRow[i];
      vector<float> nextClassVecData;
      for(int j = 0; j < tblVecData.size(); ++j) {
        nextClassVecData.push_back(tblVecData[j]);
      }
      nextClassVec.push_back(nextClassVecData);
    }
  }
};
```

This does a deep copy of the vector data (at least that's the idea - I haven't compiled this). There is [very] likely to be much better solutions than this (like using the copy() algorithm); if so the folks are welcome to improve it.

Other notes:

- It really doesn't have to be this cumbersome IMO. But I am resisting
  wanting to improve your question
- your vec.assign in its present form is repeatedly running on items
  already processed. I take it to just  mean in pseudocode that you
  want to copy elements